# Is there any problem in calling a static method from type name in python?

Tags: python-3.x, static-methods

Should I be aware of any problem that could arise from doing this?

Example:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    
    @staticmethod
    def add1(a):
        return a+1

x = A(1)
y = type(x).add1(2)
```

My use case would be calling a static method that processes data that was generated by an object that we cannot use anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Simple test for identity gives us:

```py
x = A(1)
print(type(x) is A)
True
print(type(x).add is A.add)
True
```

So based on that there should not be any problem, but I am not 100% sure. Although I would probably go with accessing `x.__class__` property, which is in my opinion more intuitive.

EDIT: From Python documentation regarding the `type` function:

> With one argument, return the type of an object. The return value is a type object and generally the same object as returned by `object.__class__`.